# no viable alternative at input '<' cassandra map

Tags: cassandra

I created a type as such

```
create type (
  street text,
  city text,
  state text,
  zip int
);
```

then tried to create a table like this:

```
create table (
  fName text PRIMARY KEY,
  addressess map<text, frozen<address>>
);
```

but I keep getting this error though:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:78 no viable alternative at input '<' (..., addresses <string, frozen [<]...)">
```

I followed this doc on datastax and I'm on version 2.1.8
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html

Comment: That looks valid to me, although you are missing your primary key definition and table/type names.  Is that intentional?

Comment: no, sorry, that was a typo...fName is the primary key

Comment: Are you sure you are on cassandra 2.1 and not cassandra 2.0?  That's the only explanation I can think of so far.

Comment: yep...I ran select release_version from system.local and got back 2.1.8

Comment: I figured it out...I was missing the map when I typed it into the terminal...dummy me